# Silverlight 4.0 and MySql

Tags: mysql, silverlight-4.0

I installed `MySql Server` 5.5 and the `.NET` connection 6.X.
How do I go about opening a connection from my `silverlight` application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't... unless that .NET connection 6.X supports Silverlight, which I think it doesn't. SL has no support for direct database connections like this. You're supposed to use a web service as a proxy for your db needs.